# C++/Eclipse cdt, avoid to implement the same function but with different signature

Tags: c++, eclipse

I don't know whether what I'm about to ask depends from the tool I'm using or from the language itself but anyway.

I have a situation where I have "one method" declared several times with different signature. Such as:

```
class my_class {
   public:
      int getData();
      int getData() const;
      my_class operator+(my_class&,my_class&);
      my_class operator+(const my_class&, const my_class&) const;
      //other operators, other functions etc with similar feature
   private:
      int data;
};
```

As you can imagine the implementation would be always the same, it's just the signature the issue. Is there a way to avoid to write two times the same implementation of such functions?

At the beginning I thought a casting from the type to const type would have been performed, but apparently I was wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Your overloads aren't declared properly. A class member binary operator can take only one parameter, the other is implicitly `this`. Otherwise you can't use it with infix notation.
2. You don't need both overloads. The operator shouldn't change the operands, so the const version alone is enough.

So that leaves us with:

```
class my_class {
   public:
      int getData();
      int getData() const;
      my_class operator+(const my_class&) const;
      //other operators, other functions etc with similar feature
   private:
      int data;
};
```

Or the non-member version:

```
class my_class {
   public:
      int getData();
      int getData() const;
      friend my_class operator+(const my_class&, const my_class&);
      //other operators, other functions etc with similar feature
   private:
      int data;
};

my_class operator+(const my_class&, const my_class&) {
 // code
}
```

---

As for `getData()`. It retunsa copy of your data, and I assume it doesn't modify the instance. Then the `const` overload is also enough.

Comment: @user8469759, no need to apologize. Did my answer help you? Then please consider accepting it.

Comment: I'm writing some code now for the operator+, what about the  "getData"?

Comment: So shall I leave only the constant version?

Comment: Can you please have a look to my update and answer to the 4 questions? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user8469759, one question at a time, please. My post answered your original one. Now it doesn't because of the extra question.

Comment: Hmmm my apologies xD.

Comment: I suggest You rollback your changes, and post the update as a separate question. Help keep the site nice and tidy.