# Understanding some C++ code involving const type&

Tags: c++, c++11

With reference to the code reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462182/c-eclipse-cdt-avoid-to-implement-the-same-function-but-with-different-signatu/40462270?noredirect=1#comment68170908_40462270) I have the following questions to make sure I understood what's going on.

```
class Integer32 {
public:
    Integer32() {
        this->setData(0);
    }
    Integer32(const Integer32& x) {
        this->setData(x.getData());
    }
    Integer32(int data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
    Integer32& operator=(const Integer32& x) {
        if (this != &x) {
            this->setData(x.getData());
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Integer32& operator=(const int& x) {
        this->setData(x);
        return *this;
    }
    Integer32 operator+(const Integer32& x) const {
        return Integer32(this->getData() + x.getData());
    }
    void setData(int data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
    int getData() const {
        return data;
    }
private:
    int data;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Integer32 a, b, c;
    a = 7;
    b = 9;
    a = b;
    c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

1. `a, b` are non const `Integer32`, right?
2. `b = 9` calls my operator overload `=`, what happens to the literal `9`? my operator requires a `const int&`, while I'm passing a literal constant.
3. `a = b` requires `b` to be `const Integer32&`, is a casting here performed from `Integer32` to `const Integer32&`?
4. `c = a + b`, are both `a,b` casted to constants?

Comment: couldn't you use a debugger? If casting/constructor or assignment operator is performed, the respective member function will be called.

Comment: These aren't a typical "get yourself a debugger" questions. It's rather - how does language in this particular example work.

Answer (score 5):

> a, b are non const Integer32, right?

Yes. (I don't see `const` anywhere, do you?)

> b = 9 calls my operator overload =, what happens to the literal 9? my
>   operator requires a const int&, while I'm passing a literal constant.

`9` is a temporary of type `int`. Temporaries aren't allowed to be passed as reference except when the reference is `const`. In this case that's true and the temporary's lifetime is extended allowing `Integer32& operator=(const int& x)`.

> a = b requires b to be const Integer32&, is a casting here performed
>   from Integer32 to const Integer32&?

Yes. An implicit cast is done by the compiler.

> c = a + b, are both a,b casted to constants?

Same goes for this question. First `Integer32 operator+(const Integer32& x)` is done with operands `a` and `b`. (b is implicitly converted to `const Integer32&`) Then `Integer32& operator=(const Integer32& x)` is done with operands `c` and the result of the expression `a.operator+(b)` which is a temporary `Integer32`.

Comment: `9` is a prvalue. When binding a reference to prvalues of builtin type, a temporary is created and copy-initialized.

Comment: Regarding "Yes" , note that this is a direct reference binding - casting to reference type is quite different to non-reference casts. This might be what OP is hung up on

Comment: I didn't mean const references only. E.g `int&& c = 9;`

Comment: @GillBates Thanks for answering. What operator is used to perform the casting to const (especially in for the object Integer32)? I'm not entirely sure what happens when a casting to const is performed, because in my class declaration there's nothing about it.

Comment: @user8469759 None. As M.M stated it isn't quite casting but rather reference binding. This is a part of the language and can't be customized through the use of custom operators. Your lvalue just becomes a const reference because the compiler wants it to be one.

Comment: I need to read something about "reference binding". Is it reported in the standard maybe?

Comment: Yeah it's under the "Initialization" section, where the thing being initialized has reference type.

Comment: I understand I'm annoying right now, here is the standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf, section inizialization goes from page 253 to 259, where is specifically metioned the reference binding?